# What is the normal derivative of a PDE?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

Kreyszig's introduction of the **normal derivative**

$u_n = \partial u / \partial n$

leaves me a bit puzzled as to what variable $n$ is if $u$ is a function of $x$ and $y$.

The trailing example uses a condition for one of the boundaries specified as
$u_n = 6x$
and the solution steps deduces
$\dfrac {\partial u_{ij}} {\partial n} = \dfrac {\partial u_{ij}} {\partial y} = 6x$
out of thin air.

So what exactly is the normal derivative? Is it simply an interpretation of a normal vector standing up from $u$ if it's treated as a surface, i.e. 
$\dfrac {\partial u_{ij}} {\partial n} = \dfrac {\partial u_{ij}} {\partial x} + \dfrac {\partial u_{ij}} {\partial y}$ 
?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [normal derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative#Normal_derivative) is a directional derivative in a direction that is outwardly normal (perpendicular) to some curve, surface or hypersurface (that is assumed from context) at a specific point on the aforementioned curve, surface or hypersurface. If $\mathbf{N}$ is the [normal vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_normal) then $\partial u / \partial n$ stands for $\vec{\nabla} u \cdot \mathbf{N}$. From the example you give it seems that $\mathbf{N}=(0,1)$ on whatever boundary is being considered.